# Explanation of "The absence of evidence, they say, is not the evidence of absence."

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does this statement mean? Please explain

> The absence of evidence, they say, is not the evidence of absence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The absence of evidence* that a person has been in a particular place (probably a crime scene) doesn't prove that they were *not* there (absent) at the time something happened. It only means that there is no proof that they *were* there.